# RC circuit equations

Tags: circuit-analysis

I've been presented with the following circuit and asked to find an expression for Vc in terms of time

[image: cct]

My working is this:

$$
V_S = V_R + V_C\\
I_R = I_C\\
$$

$$
\frac{V_R}R = C\frac{dV_C}{dt}\\
\frac{V_S - V_C}R = C\frac{dV_C}{dt}\\
dt = \frac{RC}{V_S - V_C}dV_C\\
$$
integrating
$$
t = -RC\ln(V_S - V_C)\\
\frac{-t}{RC} = \ln(V_S - V_C)\\
$$
taking exponentials
$$
\exp(\frac{-t}{RC}) = V_S - V_C\\
V_C = V_S - \exp(\frac{-t}{RC})
$$

But I know the answer should be
$$
V_C = V_S - V_S\exp(\frac{-t}{RC})
$$

Can anyone see where my missing Vs has gone?

Comment: You've forgotten the constant of integration.

Comment: \$ln(V_s-V_c)=\frac{-t}{RC}+K\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial conditions and constant of integration.

$$\begin{align*}
I_R &= \frac{V_R}{R} = \frac{V_S-V_C}{R}\\
I_C &= C\cdot\frac{\textrm{d}V_C}{\textrm{d}t}\\
\textrm{when }I_R\textrm{ is positive, d}&V_C\textrm{ is also positive}\\\\
&\therefore I_R = I_C\\\\\\\\
\frac{V_S-V_C}{R} &= C\cdot\frac{\textrm{d}V_C}{\textrm{d}t} \\\\
\textrm{d} t&=\frac{R \:C}{V_S-V_C}\:\:\textrm{d}V_C \\\\
\int \textrm{d} t&=-R\: C\int \frac{\textrm{d}V_C}{V_C-V_S}\\\\
\textrm{setting }u=V_C-V_S,\quad &\therefore \textrm{d}u=\textrm{d}V_C\\\\
\int \textrm{d} t&=-R\: C\int \frac{\textrm{d}u}{u}\\\\
t+C_0&=-R\:C\:\operatorname{ln}\left(u\right)\\\\
-\frac{t}{R\:C\:}-\frac{C_0}{R\:C\:}&=\operatorname{ln}\left(V_C-V_S\right)\\\\
e^{\frac{-t}{R\:C\:}}\cdot e^{\frac{-C_0}{R\:C\:}}&=V_C-V_S\\\\
A_0\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{R\:C\:}}&=V_C-V_S\\\\
\textrm{from the initial conditions at }t=0\textrm{ and }V_C&=0,\textrm{ we know }A_0=-V_S\\\\
\therefore -V_S\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{R\:C\:}}&=V_C-V_S\\\\
V_S-V_S\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{R\:C\:}}&=V_C\\\\
V_C&=V_S\cdot\left(1- e^{\frac{-t}{R\:C\:}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @ACarter Yeah. That pesky \$C_0\$ above. I think most of us have been bitten by rushing forward and forgetting a constant of integration. (Sometimes, one gets lucky and the fact that it was missed doesn't seem to hinder the result.)